# Can I auto-mount all users in /home (using `*` key) except one?

Tags: automounting, sles, autofs

Starting on a server where `/home` had just one user, I thought "adding" the home directories of the other users via NFS using automount's `*` and `&`.
Also the NFS has a home directory (but an older configuration) for the local user that has a local home.

I have a map file saying

```
* -bg,rw,nfsvers=3 server.domain.org:/exports/home/&
```

used to map the files.
The idea was to insert the local user's name as *key* before the `*` line, so the `*` line wont ever match.
However there are two problems:

1. I don't know what to write in the line with the key matching the local user to make automount **not** mount anything
2. It seems automount starts mounting an empty filesystem type `autofs` *over* the existing local `/home`, so the local user's home disappears.

So it seems it's not possible, or is there another (half-way elegant) way?

Comment: Given that 'remote:/home` is going to be mounted over local `/home`, I think the best you can do is move the existing userdir to somewhere else. Of course, you will have to modify config files underneath it to point to the new location.

Comment: I thought about that: Mounting the local user's home at a different mount point, and then include an autofs key to bind-mount it to the real `/home`. Haven't tried yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve that problem by a proof of concept:

I added an extra line on top of my map file, so that it looked like this:

```
xxx -bind :/tmp
* -bg,rw,nfsvers=3 server.domain.org:/exports/home/&
```

So now when listing `/home/xxx` I was presented the contents of `/tmp`.

To complete the solution just mount the original local `/home` to a different mount point like `/localhome` and replace `xxx` with the local user and `/tmp` with `/localhome/&`.